# Use of string formatter causing "Access violation writing location" from an Unhandled Exception

Tags: c

I wrote the following C program in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#define _CRP_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
      char b[12];
      printf("Input: ");
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf_s("%s", &b);
      printf("output: %d",b);
      getchar();
      return(0);
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x63F53FD4 (msvcr120d.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00510000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

it happens when I use %s.How do I fix it?

Comment: @โอ ศราวุธ you have used a wrong tag. Please fix to attract the right audience.

Comment: Per this MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx I believe you meant scanf_s("%s", b); rather than scanf_s("%s", &b);

Comment: try `scanf_s("%11s", b, sizeof(b));` or `scanf_s("%s", b, sizeof(b));` : You must specify the buffer size in `scanf_s` for `%s`.

Comment: this line: fflush(stdin); is specifically stated in the the standard to result in undefined behaviour.  suggest: the following line (a call to scanf_s) have a leading space in the format string, so white space, like newline, be skipped

Comment: this line: scanf_s("%s", &b);  the 'b' is an array and using the name of an array always results in a pointer, so the line should be: memset( b, 0x00, sizeof(b) ); scanf("%11s", b); <-- note no '&' before the 'b' and with the array set to all '\0' no need to append a '\0' after the call to scanf.  using scanf_s requires an additional parameter that is the max size of the (in this case) %s max number of characters allowed to be input.

Comment: It Work!!!Thanks for every help.

Answer (score 0):

try `scanf_s("%11s", b, sizeof(b));` or `scanf_s("%s", b, sizeof(b));` : You must specify the buffer size in `scanf_s` for `%s`.
                    – BLUEPIXY